# How to add ng-model to an at runtime created html object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm having a simple html form like this

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <form action="" ng-controller="testController" id="parent">
    </form>
</div>
```

And now I want to add an input field from javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('testController',testController);
function testController($scope){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var form = document.getElementById('parent');

    input.setAttribute("type","number");
    input.setAttribute("id","testId");
    input.setAttribute("name", "test");
    input.setAttribute("ng-model","test");  
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

The input field also get's generated as expected

```
<input type="number" id="testId" name="test" ng-model="test">
```

but the ng-model between this input field and `$scope.test` is not working.

Comment: it is a wrong practice to do dom manipulation in controller... you need to complile the new element using `$compile` service

Comment: Use a directive for DOM manipulation and compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Important: *You should not make dom manipulation in a cotroller, you need to use a directive to do that.*

That said, even in a directive if you are creating a dynamic element you need to compile it to have angular behavior applied to it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [], function() {})

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$compile', testController]);

function testController($scope, $compile) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  var form = document.getElementById('parent');

  input.setAttribute("type", "number");
  input.setAttribute("id", "testId");
  input.setAttribute("name", "test");
  input.setAttribute("ng-model", "test");
  $compile(input)($scope)
  form.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <form action="" ng-controller="testController" id="parent">
    <div>test: {{test}}</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't ngModel a directive? or do i understand directive in a wrong way?

Comment: you can create your own directives, whenever there is a need to manipulate DOM, use directives, or make you own